# How can I divide the contents of a string based on a chemical formula?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have to validate a string that is supposed to mimic a Chemical formula (excluding symbols like charge (+/-)), and it has to respect how the formula should be written (correct use of parenthesis, two letters maximum per element, and an absence of non-alphanumeric characters that are not the parenthesis ). However, it doesn't need to know if the molecule submitted is capable of existing - only if the string itself is valid.

Let's say that the contents of the string to validate look like this: "Na3(CO2)3"

Assuming that I already validated that the string is not empty and that it doesn't have any illegal characters or incorrect use of the parenthesis, it would be necessary to separate the string in, let's say symbols, so I can store the individual elements (and I mean all the elements. In this case, 3 Na and 3 CO2 particles).

So it should be divided like this:

```
"Na",
"3",
"(",
"C"
"O"
"2"
")"
"3"
```

I tried to divide it with a `for` but there are so many conditions to "separate" the string that I am not sure how can I do it correctly - especially considering that an element can either have 1 or 2 characters.

For the moment, my code looks like this ignoring the other stuff to validate that is easy to do.

```
public boolean validerFormuleChimique(String formuleChimique, StringWrapper message)
{
  ArrayList<String> symbolSubmited = new ArrayList<String>();
  symbolSubmited.add(new String());
        symbolSubmited.get(0).equals("");
        for (int i =0; i< formuleChimique.length(); i++)
        {
            if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(formuleChimique.charAt(i)) &&
                    ( formuleChimique.charAt(i) != '(' || 
                      formuleChimique.charAt(i) != ')' ))
            {
                message.contenu = messagesErreur[9];
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
}
```

Another problem I can see with the code is that I cannot modify a String using a += in an ArrayList. I could use an array, but there is no way to know how long or short a formula can be before verification. So there is that.

I expect that not only can I validate the formula, but that I can store each and every "symbol" of the formula (including the numbers and parenthesis) in a ArrayList of strings.

Comment: Writing a parser can be a tricky thing, I think you need take some time and write down the rules and "grammar" for the string to parse. Like "lowercase letter together with previous letter is an element" or "Uppercase letter followed by another uppercase letter makes up an element by itself" and so on. Maybe it would also makes things easier to create a simple Element class so you wouldn't have to keep track of so many strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are iterating through you basically need to be calculating tokens.  Parentheses are easy tokens.  Numbers are pretty easy - you just have to keep going as long as the next character is a number.

The real trick is the characters for the element names.  There are a couple of ways to approach this.  If you can count on the elements using standard symbols you can simply assume that a lowercase is a continuation of the current token while an upper case is the start of a new token.    Therefore NaCl would correctly turn into two tokens, Na and Cl, and CO2 would turn into three tokens, C, O, and 2.

If you cannot count on standardized capitalization your life gets harder.

Comment: Again - the real key is that you'll need to look at the next character (if there is one!) in addition to the current.

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume that a lowercase is a continuation of the current token, you can use this example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "Na3(CO2)3";
    Pattern r =  Pattern.compile("A[cglmrstu]|B[aehikr]?|C[adeflmnorsu]?|D[bsy]|E[rsu]|F[elmr]?|G[ade]|H[efgos]?|I[nr]?|Kr?|L[airuv]|M[dgnot]|N[abdeiop]?|Os?|P[abdmortu]?|R[abefghnu]|S[bcegimnr]?|T[abcehilm]|U(u[opst])?|V|W|Xe|Yb?|Z[nr]|\\d|\\(|\\)");
    Matcher matcher =r.matcher(test);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
        System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Start index: 0 End index: 2 Na
Start index: 2 End index: 3 3
Start index: 3 End index: 4 (
Start index: 4 End index: 5 C
Start index: 5 End index: 6 O
Start index: 6 End index: 7 2
Start index: 7 End index: 8 )
Start index: 8 End index: 9 3
```